# jdoc style values for Joomla 2.5 template

Tags: html, joomla, joomla-template

I'm creating an HTML5 template in Joomla 2.5 and I wanted to know what are my options for the style attribute in the code below?

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" style="???" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `templates\system\html\modules.php`. There are defined system styles, like `xhtml`, `rounded` etc. You can also see the code how each style will be rendered.

If you want to add your own style, you need to create a new `module chrome`. In your template html folder (not system, don't edit above file), create file called `modules.php`.

Inside, make a function like this

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

function modChrome_mystyle($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
    if (!empty ($module->content)) : ?>
             <div class="moduletable">
                  <?php if ($module->showtitle != 0) : ?>
                       <h3><?php echo $module->title; ?></h3>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                  <?php echo $module->content; ?>
            </div>
    <?php endif;
}
```

This way you can create custom module outputs, just edit the code the way you want.

Then, in your template file, include the module with

```
     <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" style="mystyle" />
```